# SSL not allowed in two configs after nginx/1.11.4 / Ubu 16.04 update

Tags: ssl, nginx, qemu, ubuntu-16.04, libvirt

This was working prior to nginx/1.11.4 and update to Ubuntu 16.04 (and it was on 1.11.x before). There are two sites configured to use SSL on a virtual IP (libvirt). When that didn't work (somehow it always landed on the first config alphabetically with SSL), I changed it to use two different virtual IPs and changed libvirt routing two real IPs to 192.168.122.10 and the other to 192.168.122.11, respectively. Now it's simply giving a handshake failure.

```
server {
        listen 192.168.122.11:443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.domain2.org domain2.org;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/domains/domain2.org.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/domains/domain2.org.err;
        root /app/domain2.org/html;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain2.org.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain2.org.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
        ssl_ecdh_curve  prime256v1;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        include /etc/nginx/include/php.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/include/restrictions.conf;
}

server {
        listen 192.168.122.10:443 ssl http2;
        server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com *.domain1.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/domains/domain1.com.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/domains/domain1.com.err;
        root /app/domain1.com/html;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain1.cert;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain1.pkey;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
        ssl_ecdh_curve  prime256v1;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        include /etc/nginx/include/restrictions.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/include/php.conf;
}
```

This is just the standard nginx from nginx.org packaging, and yes it has SNI. I have no idea why this would suddenly stop working.

```
root@production:/etc/nginx/conf.d# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.11.4
built by gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016 (running with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016)
TLS SNI support enabled
```

Comment: What does an https://ssllabs.com server scan say?

Comment: @vcsjones
It can't connect.
`afk4life@K55N:~$ curl -vvI https://domain2.org/`
`*   Trying 46.xxx.xxx.xxx...`
`* Connected to domain2.org (46.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)`
`* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
`* found 704 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs`
`* ALPN, offering http/1.1`
`* gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed`
`* Closing connection 0`
`curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed`